# Wrong version of Python linked

Tags: python, pip, launcher

So I deleted python3.6 from Windows 10, and now whenever I try to 'pip install' something I get this following error:
`"Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"d:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python.exe"  "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install tensorflow': The system cannot find the file specified."`

I know the work around is just to `python -m pip install <...>` instead which defaults to the python version I am currently running, but I am wondering how to address the root cause of the issue.

Comment: This might still be in your PATH, have you removed it?

Comment: @12944qwerty That did the trick! However now its defaulting to python3.8... which is also not the one set in the interpreter

Comment: Why don't you just use conda ? You can specify which version you want per environment.

Comment: @PriyankTrivedi I tried conda for a while... but somehow messed up dependencies for those too

Comment: yeah, but you can just remove an env and create a new one without messing up system wide dependency, also once setup just export environment to '.yml' and import as is when needed.